# Redirect all webpages to HTTPS after user logs in?

Tags: php, javascript, http, .htaccess, https

I'm building a mixed https/http website using PHP. When the user logs in (via https) I set a secure cookie with the username and session. After logging in (so once the cookie is set) I want to redirect all traffic to https as there is user specific content on each page once logged in. Originally I had the website set up to use only https, but after searching around for a bit it seems that it is better to use SSL only when needed (so when users are not logged in http would be used). Can I achieve this using PHP/javascript or by adding some command regarding cookies to my .htaccess file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you operate with cookies and session, you should always use HTTPS all the time. Otherwise the session cookie over HTTP can be obtained by a third party easily. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Make sure you use session_regenerate_id() at login, so the previous session id send over http is never useful. This will prevent some of the dangers of session hijacking.

Comment: _'previous session-id over http'_? As far as I am concerned, that one shouldn't exists / shouldn't be created in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is assuming you have configured your sessions to work only over HTTPS, otherwise, this is just pretend-security (use [`session.cookie_secure`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure)).

You can also set a (http, not https) cookie on login:

```
setcookie('wantshttps','true',0,'/');
```

And in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} wantshttps=true
RewriteCOnd %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCOnd %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,QSA]
```

So remember to set it to false or unset it if you detect the cookie to be 'true', but a non-logged in user (session expired and the like).

Comment: The HTTPS protocoll should prevent Man-In-The-Middle attacks, but this `wantshttps` cookie is meant to be sent over HTTP. That makes it kind of useless, because in this case it can be manipulated, and the session cookie is sent plaintext too.

Comment: @martinstoeckli: thats the point: anyone _may_ know the user wants HTTPS, but the session-cookie is _configured_ to be only sent over _HTTPS_. This just catches a request to a page (which the user would end up seeing as a logged out user / guest), and redirects it to the https page where the user _is_ logged in. Of course, most requests / internal links would automatically be https, but this catches links from other sites redirecting the user from the logged-out-http-variant to the logged-in-https veriant.

Comment: In short: go ahead, manipulate the `wantshttps` cookie... What happens? Either set to true -> user goes to https variant, mitm-attack can no longer take place, or set to false -> the user sees logged out pages as any guest would see, and the user does not send any session cookies identifying him.

Comment: @Wrikken - Ok that sounds better, but it should really be mentioned, that the session cookie must be sent to HTTPS pages only. Though if you do this, then the session cookie will not be sent with the HTTP request, and the "rewritten" HTTPS page cannot recreate the session.

Comment: Aight, I assumed it was implied, but I'll add it to the answer. The HTTPS-pages redirected to should have no problems with the session (it's an outside redirect, not internal), so I don't see what you mean with _"the "rewritten" HTTPS page cannot recreate the session"_.

Comment: @Wrikken - Hope i understand it correctly, but in my opinion this is only a rewriting of the URL, not a redirecting. To tell the browser that it should make another request (external), you would need the `[R]` parameter.

Comment: @martinstoeckli: this will do a redirect, because another protocol is given (any change in host, protocol, or port will trigger it). You can add the `[R]` if you like for clarities sake, but you can test it yourself, it will redirect rather then doing an internal rewrite even without one.

Answer (score 1):

As far as URLs in HTML are considered, relative URLs should handle this, as they use the protocol of the base address. If references to other sites are needed, you can use URLs with protocol name and colon omitted, e.g. //www.example.com/foo which will get interpreted as http://www.example.com/foo or https://www.example.com/foo depending on the protocol of the referring page.

Comment: Good tip, unless you arrive at a (deeplink) of the website from another source / link without the https, in which case 'suddenly being logged out' from the point of view of the visitor (who doesn't notice the http/https difference) is confusing for them. So while this is a valid comment, and should of course be used for internal links, detecting & redirecting is a bit of gravy for your customers.

Comment: @Wrikken - Either the whole requested page is protected, then a HTTP link should **not** display the content, or the page is public, then you can leave out the user specific content when requested with HTTP.

Comment: That's the point: there will be no user-specific content over HTTP, but there's a lot of applications where a link would be valid for both guests (meager content) and logged in users (extra features), which wouldn't be reflected in url, but just by merit of being logged in. The initial url itself would be send unprotected, yes, and I assume, as this url is an outside link, being able to snoop that the user visits this link (with only public content) is not a safety concern.

Answer (score 0):

look at php.net `header()` function